# Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(scripts) in NX storybook workspace

Tags: angular, storybook, nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

I have implemented the [following article](https://nx.dev/recipes/storybook/one-storybook-for-all) on my NX workspace in order to have one host to all of my Storybook stories.

One of the components demand an external library. I'm trying to add the script file to project.json (`"scripts": ["node_modules/leader-line/leader-line.min.js"],`) and get the folloing error when running storybook:

> Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(scripts).

This is my project.json:

```
{
  "name": "storybook-host",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/storybook-host/src",
  "prefix": "inf",
  "tags": [],
  "projectType": "library",
  "targets": {
    "storybook": {
      "executor": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
      "options": {
        "port": 4400,
        "configDir": "libs/storybook-host/.storybook",
        "browserTarget": "storybook-host:build-storybook",
        "compodoc": false
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "quiet": true
        }
      }
    },
    "build-storybook": {
      "executor": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputDir}"],
      "options": {
        "outputDir": "dist/storybook/storybook-host",
        "configDir": "libs/storybook-host/.storybook",
        "browserTarget": "storybook-host:build-storybook",
        "compodoc": false,
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": ["libs/root/styles/src/partials"]
        },
        "styles": [
          "libs/root/styles/src/global.scss",
          "libs/root/styles/src/overrides/browser.scss",
          "libs/root/styles/src/overrides/primeng.scss",
          "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": ["node_modules/leader-line/leader-line.min.js"],
        "assets": [
          {
            "input": "libs/root/assets/src/assets",
            "glob": "**/*.!(ts)",
            "output": "./src"
          }
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "quiet": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I see some issues online referring to `angular.json`'s "es5BrowserSupport" and "extractCss" but those weren't helpful.